# How to get rid of overflow cutting divs in a list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

We are using a list for listing items(etc) on a website and are using overflow. As well, we have divs - when the mouse is hovering over the site's items, the divs will be displayed. Some items are very close to the scroll bar and their div is cutting like so:

[image: example]

Any help on how we can have the div continue over the scroll bar instead of cutting off at the scroll bar would be great.

```css
ul.purchase-list {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.purchase-list li {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #b200ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.purchase-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  background: #392067;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999 !important;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.purchase-hover:hover {
  display: none !important;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}

ul.purchase-list li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.purchase img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.purchase span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  top: -17px;
  background: #b200ff;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<li class="item">
  <div class="purchase">
    <img src="-" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1">
    <img src="-">
  </div>
  <div class="purchase-hover">
    <div class="purchase-hover-top">
      <h2>Test</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="purchase-hover-content">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <h5>Test
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: @Ajjar just added some! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Z-Index has to deal with the layers things appear, so I would mess with the Z-Index of the div and that of the body, and try to make sure the div Z is > than the body Z.